# How to connect asp.net web forms web application with mongodb

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, web, connection

I am trying to connect asp.net web forms application to MongoDB I downloaded, MongoDB driver, and I want to connect it from web config with DB authentication, I did to connect with the URL string but i want to connect with from web config.

Comment: We're not sure what you have downloaded, please provide minimal example to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I downloaded MongoDBDriver from Nugut Package Manager

Answer (score 0):

In web.config, inside `<configuration> </configuration>` , add the following:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="connectionString" value="Server=localhost:27017"/>
</appSettings>
```

If you want to connect to a distant Mongo database, configure the value of connectionString to include username and password (see the docs : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)

See this:https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/656093/Connecting-MongoDB-with-ASP-NET or https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/897/mongodb-aspnet-webapi-connection

Comment: Is there any way to define username and password in the connection string in appSettings of the web config if yes, please give me an example I can't understand docs there is not the solution with web config is given.

Comment: `<add key="connectionString" value="Server=Username:Password@localhost:27017/nameofDatabase"/>` . Replace "localhost:27017 " with the address of your distant database .